# Clicking on link in html doesnt give a response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes, pusher

For the last 2 weeks, I have been trying to get this to work but I can't seem to find the problem. when I click on a user to chat with it doesn't seem to create a chat room between the two. I have followed that tutorial https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-aspnet/ but edited a few things like my database. After debugging it seems like it doesn't do anything when I click on one of the user links.

I have tried renaming everything and starting all over again

My View with javascript:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <aside class="main visible-md visible-lg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default users__bar">
                            <div class="panel-heading users__heading">
                                Contacts (@ViewBag.allUsers.Count)
                            </div>
                            <div class="__no__chat__">
                                <p>Select a contact to chat with</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body users__body">
                                <ul id="contacts" class="list-group">

                                    @foreach (var user in @ViewBag.allUsers)
                                    {
                                        <a class="user__item contact-@user.Id" href="#" data-contact-id="@user.Id" data-contact-name="@user.FirstName">
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="avatar">
                                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/no_avatar.png")">
                                                </div>
                                                <span>@user.FirstName</span>
                                                <div class="status-bar"></div>
                                            </li>
                                        </a>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>


        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 chat__body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="list-group chat__main"></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="chat__type__body">
                    <div class="chat__type">
                        <textarea id="msg_box" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessage">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat__typing">
                    <span id="typerDisplay"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    let currentContact = null; // Holds current contact
    let newMessageTpl =
        `<div>
        <div id="msg-{{id}}" class="row __chat__par__">
          <div class="__chat__">
            <p>{{body}}</p>
            <p class="delivery-status">Delivered</p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>`;

    // select contact to chat with
    $('.user__item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        currentContact = {
            Id: $(this).data('contact-id'),
            FirstName: $(this).data('contact-name'),
        };

        $('#contacts').find('li').removeClass('active');

        $('#contacts .contact-' + currentContact.Id).find('li').addClass('active');
        getChat(currentContact.Id);
    });

    // get chat data
    function getChat(contact_id) {
        $.get("/contact/conversations/" + contact_id)
            .done(function(resp) {
                var chat_data = resp.data || [];
                loadChat(chat_data);
            });
    }

   ...
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] == null)
            {
                return Redirect("/");
            }

            //var currentUser = (Models.tblUser) Session["UserID"];


            using (var db = new Models.ChatContext())
            {
                int currentUserId = (int) Session["UserID"];
                var currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
                ViewBag.allUsers = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUser.Id).ToList();
                ViewBag.currentUser = currentUser;
            }


            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult ConversationWithContact(int contact)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] == null)
            {
                return Json(new {status = "error", message = "User is not logged in"});
            }

            var currentUser = (Models.tblUser)Session["UserID"];

            var conversations = new List<Models.tblMessage>();

            using (var db = new Models.ChatContext())
            {
                conversations = db.Conversations.Where(c => (c.receiverId == currentUser.Id
                                                             && c.senderId == contact) ||
                                                            (c.receiverId == contact
                                                             && c.senderId == currentUser.Id))
                    .OrderBy(c => c.created_at)
                    .ToList();
            }

            return Json(
                new {status = "success", data = conversations},
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );
        }
```

My Message model and chatcontext:

```
public class ChatContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChatContext() : base("TrinityEntities")
        {
        }

        public static ChatContext Create()
        {
            return new ChatContext();
        }

        public DbSet<tblUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<tblMessage> Conversations { get; set; }
    }

public class tblMessage
    {
        public tblMessage()
        {
            status = messageStatus.Sent;
        }

        public enum messageStatus
        {
            Sent,
            Delivered
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int senderId { get; set; }
        public int receiverId { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public messageStatus status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    }
```

My routeconfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Default",
            //    url: "",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Profile",
                url: "profile",
                defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "Home",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChatRoom",
                url: "chat",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "GetContactConversations",
                url: "contact/conversations/{contact}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "ConversationWithContact", contact = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PusherAuth",
                url: "pusher/auth",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "AuthForChannel" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SendMessage",
                url: "send_message",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "SendMessage" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MessageDelivered",
                url: "message_delivered/{message_id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "MessageDelivered", message_id = "" }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a line that you may have missed in the instructions just below the ChatContext bit:

> "To retrieve the messages, we will create a route for
>   /contact``/conversations/{contact}. This route will accept a contact
>   ID, retrieve messages between the current user and the contact, then
>   return the messages in a JSON response. "

Currently, in the javascript the getChat() function sends a request to `/contact/conversation/{contactId}`. For MVC projects the default route format is `/{controllerName}/{actionName}/{parameter}`. So the call in your javascript currently looks for a controller called `ContactController` and then an action on that controller called `Conversation`. As you know, these don't currently exist in your project, so you'll need to set up a route in the routeConfig that understands the incoming request and points it where you'd like it to go instead:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChatRoom",
                url: "chat/conversation/{contact}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "ConversationWithContact" }
            );
```

This should solve your problem. However, as you're just learning i think it's worth mentioning that although fine for a small app, manually mapping routes like this can lead to confusion once an app grows as you can have dozens of routes with different names pointing to controllers and actions you wouldn't have been able to guess. It's easier to maintain and understand how the code flows if it conforms to some kind of standard such as `/controllerName/actionName`

Comment: I have added my routeconfig to the question. I do have the rout but when I click on the name of a contact it reroutes me to this "http://localhost:12345/Chat#

Comment: Thanks for adding the routeConfig. The order of the routes matter, it will go for the first route it finds that matches the incoming request. As you have your default first, it will always try to match `/{controllerName}/{actionName}/{id}`. Put your default route at the bottom and it should work.

Comment: I have tried putting that route at the end. But I still get localhost:12345/Chat#, guessing I might just need to look for an alternative way to chat in asp.net?

Comment: It seems that when I click on a name. It doesnt even reach the controller